# Ensure Polly Policy Runs at Least Once

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, polly, retry-logic

So, I'm writing some retry logic for acquiring a lock using Polly. The overall timeout value will be provided by the API caller. I know I can wrap a policy in an overall timeout. However, if the supplied timeout value is too low is there a way I can ensure that the policy is executed at least once?

Obviously I could call the delegate separately before the policy is executed but I was just wondering if there was a way to express this requriment in Polly.

```
var result = Policy.Timeout(timeoutFromApiCaller)
                    .Wrap(Policy.HandleResult(false)
                                .WaitAndRetryForever(_ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
                    .Execute(() => this.TryEnterLock());
```

If `timeoutFromApiCaller` is say `1 tick` and there's a good chance it takes longer than that to reach the timeout policy then the delegate wouldn't get called (the policy would timeout and throw `TimeoutRejectedException`).

What I'd like to happen can be expressed as:

```
var result = this.TryEnterLock();

if (!result)
{
    result = Policy.Timeout(timeoutFromApiCaller)
                   .Wrap(Policy.HandleResult(false)
                               .WaitAndRetryForever(_ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
                   .Execute(() => this.TryEnterLock());
}
```

But it'd be really nice if it could be expressed in pure-Polly...

Comment: Please, share your code so far

Comment: Currently your implementation does not have a global (overall) timeout. It operates as "local". Let's suppose that timeout is 2sec, retry count is 3 and retry delay is 4sec.  It waits 2 seconds then it pauses 4 seconds before the next retry... It is important in which order you wrap your policies: if inner fails then it escalates to the outer. Local timeout: Retry > Timeout, Global Timeout: Timeout > Retry, Local+Overall: Timeout > Retry > Timeout.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCsala, would you know if what I'm trying to achieve is possible? i.e. always try once and then respect any *global* timeout?

Comment: @Nick The truth is that out of the box you got the at least one call guarantee. Because retry count 3 means 4 attempts.The initial call is the first attempt. If it fails then the retry will be triggered. So your first retry will be your second attempt.

Comment: @PeterCsala, I've modified the code slightly so it actually represents what I'm trying to acheive. I.e. I have a timeout in the outerscope and retries in the inner scope. This will throw `TimeoutRejectedException` if the outer times out before the inner gets a chance to operate. I've also indicated how I'd like it to operate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I don't understand what does it mean *1 tick*, in your case? Is it a nanosecond or greater than that? Your global timeout should be greater than your local timeout.

But as I can see you have **not specified a local one**. `TryEnterLock` should receive a TimeSpan in order to do not block the caller for infinite time. If you look at the built in sync primitives most of them provide such a capabilities: [Monitor.TryEnter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.tryenter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#overloads), [SpinLock.TryEnter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.spinlock.tryenter?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_SpinLock_TryEnter_System_TimeSpan_System_Boolean__), [WaitHandle.WaitOne](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_System_TimeSpan_), etc.

So, just to wrap it up:

```
var timeoutPolicy = Policy.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
var retryPolicy = Policy.HandleResult(false)
       .WaitAndRetryForever(_ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
var resilientStrategy = Policy.Wrap(timeoutPolicy, retryPolicy);    

var result = resilientStrategy.Execute(() => this.TryEnterLock(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)));
```

The timeout and delay values should be adjusted to your business needs. I highly encourage you to log when the global Timeout (`onTimeout` / `onTimeoutAsync`) fires and when the retries (`onRetry` / `onRetryAsync`) to be able to fine tune / calibrate these values.

---

EDIT: Based on the comments of this post

As it turned out there is no control over the `timeoutFromApiCaller` so it can be arbitrary small. (In the given example it is just a few nano-seconds, with the intent to emphasize the problem.) So, in order to have at least one call guarantee we have to make use the [Fallback policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Fallback).

Instead of calling manually upfront the `TryEnterLock` outside the policies, we should call it as **the last action** to satisfy the requirement. Because policies uses escalation, that's why whenever the *inner* fails then it delegates the problem to the next *outer* policy.

So, if the provided timeout is so tiny that action can not finish until that period then it will throw a `TimeoutRejectedException`. With the Fallback we can handle that and the action can be performed *again* but now without any timeout constraint. This will provide us the desired at least one guarantee.

```
var atLeastOnce = Policy.Handle<TimeoutRejectedException>
    .Fallback((ct) => this.TryEnterLock());
var globalTimeout = Policy.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
var foreverRetry = Policy.HandleResult(false)
       .WaitAndRetryForever(_ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

var resilientStrategy = Policy.Wrap(atLeastOnce, globalTimeout, foreverRetry);    
var result = resilientStrategy.Execute(() => this.TryEnterLock());
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. The `TryEnterLock` is an existing method which calls out to a SPROC to write a value to a db table - basically doing row-level locking without using row-level locking! (don't ask me!). I'm trying to implement a simple wait/retry/timeout as currently if we don't get the lock on the first attempt we just fail.

Comment: My concern with using Polly for this is that there is chance we never call `TryEnterLock` if the `Timeout` times out (i.e. API caller specified a silly timeout value or something slows things down before the first invocation of the delegate. So I'd like to express a wait/retry/timeout but which is *guaranteed* to execute at least once.

Comment: By `1 tick` I mean something stupid like `new TimeSpan(1)`

Comment: @Nick 1 tick around 100 nano-seconds. Are you sure that is a valid timeout in your use case where you want to make a db call? I would consider to enforce some validation logic against `timeoutFromApiCaller`. If you are using the deadline / distributed timeout pattern then you can fail fast if the remaining timeout is under a reliable threshold.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of all that and I'm just using 100ns to prove a point. I'm just concerned with determinism, i.e. I want to be able to guarantee that no matter what the timeouts Polly is always going to call my delegate at least once. Now, I can do that by always calling my delegate first before executing the policy if required however it'd be nice if Polly had a natural way to express this.

Comment: @Nick You can do that by using the **Fallback policy**. Instead of calling it directly (outside of the policies) at the first place, you can do that as a last chance. If the call wrapped inside the policies has thrown a `TimeoutRejectedException` then you can call the method itself. So, your resilient strategy would look like this: Fallback >> Retry >> Timeout >> Action. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Ah, yes that sounds like it. If you update your answer with this, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks you've been a great help Peter.